# How to change default color scheme of Nimbus L&F

Tags: java, swing, colors, look-and-feel, nimbus

I want to change Nimbus L&F color scheme in my desktop application. What is the best way for doing this?

I tried the following approach, but it requires manual definition of a color for each component of the GUI. Is there any quick-way? For instance, let's say I want to change default color scheme of Nimbus to the Blue.

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(61,89,171));
UIManager.put("menu", new Color(61,89,171));
//...
```

Comment: Are you saying that the following three color changes don't change Nimbus enough for you?
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("nimbusBlueGrey", new Color(...));
UIManager.put("control", new Color(...));

Comment: No, these colors do not change Nimbus enough. Moreover, I would like to get a ready-for-use color scheme in order to avoid the "designing" step.

Comment: depends on what, how deep you want to go, solution could be very simple, to use some custom L&Fs based on Nimbus, addional value that there are solved a few, some bugs for Key & Color & Mouse/KeyEvent

Comment: @Klausos Klausos nothing clear ftom above description, we are not guessing game here, some things works, part not

Comment: @mKorbel: I am looking for a simple approach, like you mentioned - to use some custom L&Fs based on Nimbus. How to do this?

Comment: You can download some on the internet, there's some websites out there that review and host them. Don't know of any off top of my head but I bet it's a pretty easy search to find them.